# Ruby: output not saved to file

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to give a file as input, have it changed within the program, and save the result to a file that is output. But the output file is the same as the input file. :/ Total n00b question, but what am I doing wrong?:

```
puts "Reading Celsius temperature value from data file..."
num = File.read("temperature.dat")
celsius = num.to_i
farenheit = (celsius * 9/5) + 32
puts "Saving result to output file 'faren_temp.out'"
fh = File.new("faren_temp.out", "w")
fh.puts farenheit
fh.close
```

Comment: You should take advantage of passing a block to `File` so it autocloses your files for you. See [Ruby's IO docs](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/1.9.2/IO), and search through them for how blocks are used. File inherits from IO so you'll gain lots of cool Ruby goodness automatically.

Comment: Is the value in temperature.dat -40? :-)

Comment: What do you have in the input file, and what do you have in the output file?

Comment: @matt, no :P!

@ Andrew Grimm, I fixed the problem. I was looking at the wrong file, like an idiot :) but I do have a question: why the , "w" ) in the fh = File.new line?

Comment: It indicates you're `w`riting to a file, rather than reading it. As is mentioned in the link @the Tin Man provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested the code on my machine and I have correctly the "faren_temp.out" file. Nothing is wrong ?

**Temperature.dat**

```
23
```

**faren_temp.out**

```
73
```

You just have a problem in the result. "celsius" must be a float variable in order to do a float division (not an int division).

```
puts "Reading Celsius temperature value from data file..."
num = File.read("temperature.dat")
celsius = num.to_f # modification here
farenheit = (celsius * 9/5) + 32
puts "Saving result to output file 'faren_temp.out'"
fh = File.new("faren_temp.out", "w")
fh.puts farenheit
fh.close
```

**faren_temp.out**

```
73.4
```

Comment: Because an integer divided by another integer returns an integer. 5/3 = 1 ; 5.0/3.0 = 1.666...

Comment: The point wasn't to be accurate, it was to get it to work. :P thanks though, floats are better for this application

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
puts "Reading Celsius temperature value from data file..."
farenheit = 0.0
File.open("temperature.dat","r"){|f| farenheit = (f.read.to_f * 9/5) + 32}
puts "Saving result to output file 'faren_temp.out'"
File.open("faren_temp.out","w"){|f|f.write "#{farenheit}\n"}
```